# Add css to elements rendered using js in VueJs

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to add css to elements which I rendered in a method using js.

```
buttonClicked(event) {
  console.log(event);
  let x = event.clientX - event.target.offsetLeft;
  let y = event.clientY - event.target.offsetTop;
  let ripples = document.createElement("span");
  console.log(ripples);
  ripples.style.left = x + "px";
  ripples.style.top = y + "px";
  document.getElementById("btn").appendChild(ripples);
}
```

So this is a function which get called when a user clicks on a button. I want to add the css to `<span>` which gets created in this method.

The css for `<span>` element is not rendering when I'm using scoped css. Its working fine without the scoped keyword.

I googled the problem and find this [link](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/issues/749). Here it's told we can use /deep/ or >>> operator to access the span elements. But it's still not working.

Here's the CSS

```
button >>> span {
  z-index: 3;
  position: absolute;
  background: white;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  pointer-events: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: animate 1s linear infinite;
}
```

Comment: Can you share your `.vue` file? `/deep/` selectors are only available with scss if I'm not mistaken. Also, if you're using vue-js there are much simpler ways to append children than what you're doing.

Comment: Why not add a class name and use the CSS selector span.theClassName?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are correct that it is necessary to use /deep/ or >>> with injected HTML when using *scoped*.  Your code essentially works.  However, I had to add some width and height to the actual appended element for anything visually to appear.  Not sure what the rest of your code looks like, but the following component works on my machine:

```
<template>
  <button @click="makeRipple">
    CLICK ME
  </button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Button',
  methods: {
    makeRipple (event) {
      const x = event.clientX - event.target.offsetLeft
      const y = event.clientY - event.target.offsetTop
      const ripples = document.createElement('span')
      ripples.style.left = x + 'px'
      ripples.style.top = y + 'px'
      event.target.appendChild(ripples)
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
@keyframes ripple {
 to {
   opacity: 0;
   transform: scale(4);
 }
}
button >>> span {
  z-index: 3;
  position: absolute;
  background: white;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  pointer-events: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: ripple 1s linear infinite;
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
}
</style>
```